# How do I read HTTP status code from RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring

I call Rest API using RestTemplate. Response don't has any issues.I need to get HTTP status code Like this.

> Request is ok- 200
>
> Unauthorized - 400

According to many post I met bellow answer.

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
HttpEntity<String> response = template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);

String resultString = response.getBody();
HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
```

In here used exchange method to get response.(template.exchange....)
But I used

> postForObject method

This is my code

```
public BalanceCheckResponse accountTotal(String counterAlias, String counterAuth, String subscriberType,
        String subscriberValue, String accessMode, String token) {
    
    BalanceCheckResponse objResponse = new BalanceCheckResponse();

    try {
        
        BalanceCheckRequest objRequest = new BalanceCheckRequest();
        objRequest.setCounterAlias(counterAlias);
        objRequest.setCounterAuth(counterAuth);
        objRequest.setSubscriberType(subscriberType);
        objRequest.setSubscriberValue(subscriberValue);
        objRequest.setAccessMode(accessMode);

        RestTemplate rstTemp = new RestTemplate();
        final String url = "https://ideabiz.lk/apicall/startpoint/v1/balanceCheck";
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter map =new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        messageConverters.add(map);
        //messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        rstTemp.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);

        HttpEntity<BalanceCheckRequest> entity = new HttpEntity<BalanceCheckRequest>(objRequest,headers);
        objResponse = rstTemp.postForObject(url,entity, BalanceCheckResponse.class  );
        
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(objResponse.getCurrentBalance());
    return objResponse;

}
```

In my code

> objResponse.getHeaders();

show error. What can I do in here. Do you have idea?

Comment: Hi, where do you call `objResponse.getHeaders();`?
It looks like `objResponse`is an `BalanceCheckRequest` object?

Comment: Its not. objResponseis is an BalanceCheckResponse  object.I called  it under  objResponse = rstTemp.postForObject(url,entity, BalanceCheckResponse.class  ); line.Thank you for your comment kkflf

Answer (score 5):

By default, `RestTemplate` uses a `DefaultResponseErrorHandler`, which throws an exception if you do not receive back one of the responses that are considered as successful.  This means that in the event of an error, your `e.printStackTrace();` statement will print a stack trace. (Which will most probably go unnoticed.)

If that's not good enough for you, then there is a number of ways to circumvent that behavior, one of them is by supplying your own error handler using `setErrorHandler( ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler )`.

Comment: Thank you Mike Nakis.I already used e.printStackTrace();. But I needed to get that error with efferent way.

Answer (score 3):

The return value of the `postForObject` method is the data from the received response that is deserialized to the given class, in your case `BalanceCheckResponse`.

If you need access to both returned data and status, use `postForEntity` like this:

```
ResponseEntity<BalanceCheckResponse> responseEntity = rstTemp.postForEntity(url, entity, BalanceCheckResponse.class);
objResponse = responseEntity.getBody();
HttpStatus status = responseEntity.getStatusCode();
```

Comment: This is true only if the call is a success

Comment: Thank you Bewusstsein.You saved my time.I got answer.

Comment: Thank you RC.Your correct this is true only if the call is a success. Dou you have good an idea for this.